# F# .net Core cannot use FsUnit in unit test in VsCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core, paket

I've installed FsUnit in .net core using Paket on VsCode. Unfortunately I cannot get my unit test files to reference it. I've used dotnet restore, and went to every website I could find but I'm not sure what's wrong.

I did need to add a reference to my project:

```
`<Import Project="..\.paket\Paket.Restore.targets" />`.
```

I installed Paket using chocolatey so I'm not sure if that is the issue.

Comment: If you have used paket for add nuget, you also need use 'paket restore' for restoring: https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/paket-restore.html

Comment: per the core site, https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/paket-and-dotnet-cli.html, it says that dotnet restore should do the trick. Even so, I tried paket restore and it still did not work...

Comment: Do yo have paket restore 
<Import Project="..\..\.paket\Paket.Restore.targets" />? Or maybe you can place somewhere your project?

Comment: Thanks patutin. That did help, and I use the paket controls that come with Ionide now to add a nuget package reference to current project (with project file open).

I still had issues and found that I need to close then reopen my F# file if I've imported a reference before adding a package. I've tried on two separate computers and that seems to be the root of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in a comment above, what seems to be the problem (after testing on 2 separate computers) was that I was adding a reference to FSUnit in my F# file then adding the package, and restoring the package. In order to make the reference work, I needed to then close my file and open it again after restoring the package.